# Ftplib upload failed on second upload, directory not empty

Tags: python, ftplib

I'm trying to upload all my files to a `time_name` directory (such as "170905_161330") in my ftp server.

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import ftplib
import os
import datetime

CWD = os.getcwd()
NOW_STR = str(datetime.datetime.now())
LOCAL_STR = "HDD1/AutoBackUp/" + NOW_STR[2:4]+NOW_STR[5:7]+NOW_STR[8:10]+"_"+NOW_STR[11:13]+NOW_STR[14:16]+NOW_STR[17:19]+"/"

FTP_ADDRESS = 'FTP_ADDRESS'
FTP_ID = '1'
FTP_PW = '1'
ftp = ftplib.FTP(FTP_ADDRESS, FTP_ID, FTP_PW)

for i in os.listdir(CWD):
    FILENAME = str(i)
    print(FILENAME)
    ftp.mkd(LOCAL_STR)

    LOCAL_NAME = LOCAL_STR + FILENAME
    print(str(LOCAL_NAME))
    with open(FILENAME, 'rb') as fileOBJ:
        ftp.storlines('STOR ' + str(LOCAL_NAME), fileOBJ)
ftp.quit()
```

But the error

> ftplib.error_perm: 550 HDD1/AutoBackUp/170905_160635/: Directory not empty

continues to appear, while the first file is uploaded correctly. After that, it doesn't work.

I can check my first file in ftp server, but yeah. second file doesn't exist.
I guess... `storlines` function only works when upload folder is empty.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a very rapid read of your code, I suspect that the problem is in `ftp.mkd`. You already created the directory at the first iteration of the `for` loop.

To test this error on your local system, open the terminal:

1. write a `mkdir test` command
2. write a `mkdir test` again
3. You'll see an error: `File Exist`. I think the directory not empty is gnerated from this error in the server.

Modify your code to put `ftp.mkd` **before** the for loop:

```
ftp.mkd(LOCAL_STR)
for i in os.listdir(CWD):
    FILENAME = str(i)
    print(FILENAME)

    LOCAL_NAME = LOCAL_STR + FILENAME
    print(str(LOCAL_NAME))
    with open(FILENAME, 'rb') as fileOBJ:
        ftp.storlines('STOR ' + str(LOCAL_NAME), fileOBJ)
ftp.quit()
```

and test it again. Please remember to remove the directory from the server before testing it.